# selecting and using textPath elements in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, d3.js

I would just like to check if I am missing something here.
Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?

http://bl.ocks.org/cool-Blue/11747940a2be097e5986

http://bl.ocks.org/cool-Blue/14f575ae6945769aca39

Looks like [the fix](https://chromium-cq-status.appspot.com/patch-status/1132663002/1) will be released soonish.

In Chrome
If you use camelCase, the textPath *works* but you *can't* select it.
If you use lowercase, the textpath *doesn't* work but you *can* select it.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
    text { 
      fill: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var width = 600,
        height = 200,
        svg = d3.select(document.body).append("svg")
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("width", width),
        arc = d3.svg.arc()
          .innerRadius(100)
          .outerRadius(100)
          .startAngle(0)
          .endAngle(Math.PI / 2);
    panel("textPath", 1);
    panel("textpath", 2);

    function panel(tp, id) {
      var offset = [width / 8, width / 2],
          group = svg.append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + [offset[id-1], 2* height / 3] + ")");

      group.append("text").attr("y", -120).text(tp)
      group.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("id", "path"+id);
      group.append("text")
            .append(tp)
            .attr("xlink:href", "#path"+id)
            .text("test text");
      group.append("text")
            .text("other text");

      group.append("text")
        .text(tp + " selection size: " + group.selectAll("text")
          .filter(function () {
            var p = d3.select(this).selectAll(tp);
            return p.size() && p.attr("xlink:href") == "#path" + id
          }).size())
        .attr("y", 50)
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
text { 
      fill: black;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's a known bug in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: @RobertLongson its [known](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83438) to be resolved. But it's not.

Comment: That's a webkit bug/fix. Chrome was webkit but is no longer, it has it's own bugtracker now.

Comment: @RobertLongson Ok, but Safari is WebKit still, correct? I notice the same fault in my iOS device. If not, where can I follow progress on it?

Comment: Yes, Safari is webkit. Releases take a while but I would have thought almost two years to be sufficient. You could always comment on the bug with your observations.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, but if you feel that there's something specific here that goes beyond the bug, feel free to reopen.

Comment: Ok, no problem @LarsKotthoff. Yes, it's the same bug, my point is that Jason Davies is telling me it's fixed and the bug report is showing as resolved. But clearly it's not.

Comment: @CoolBlue Sure, but that's something you'd need to raise with the Chrome developers.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, Ok thanks; my aim was to syndicate here first so that's achieved. I'll add the use case to the [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=237435).